name of animated short from MTV's Liquid Television with speed-racer guy
This animated short film was one of the many that appeared on the MTV show "Liquid Television," probably early 1990s, maybe late 1980s.
It was set several centuries in the future, and focused on a guy who was a racer in the time's equivalent of auto-racing. If I remember correctly, he drove a super-fast personal-spaceship-type thing on a huge track versus other racers in similar machines.
If I recall correctly, the guy had been racing for a long time, and the racing was so intense that he was mentally scarred from it -- to the point that he developed telekinetic powers. One scene shows him sitting at home, lost in his thoughts, and random objects like pencils and books are floating in mid-air.
not Aeon Flux, 
not Speed Racer

Was it The Running Man?
Online link: http://liquidtelevision.com/video/the-running-man/
Wikipedia description:

Zach Hugh (Banjō Ginga) is the titular "Running Man," the undefeated
  champion of the "Death Circus" racing circuit and has raced for 10
  years. Competitors race in high-speed Formula One-like craft, and
  spectators bet on the lives of these people for huge winnings. A
  Marlowe-esque reporter (Masane Tsukayama/Michael McConnohie) is sent
  to interview the mysterious Zach outside of the track and watches one
  of his races. He soon discovers Hugh has telekinetic abilities which
  he uses to destroy the other racers, after quietly observing him in
  the dark chronically over-using an interface console inside Hugh's
  penthouse. As the race ends in his favor, Hugh begins to see the
  spirits of racers who perished on the track and he continues the race
  until his vehicle goes up in flames. The Death Circus ends shortly
  afterwards, the reporter believes it was because spectators wanted to
  see how long Hugh could outlast death.


oh yes, this is it! Thank you much, and especially for the link... I thought I'd have to hunt for it, once I had the name.
